# Xamarin: App Android não carrega imagens Https

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um App Multiplataforma em Xamarin e não estou conseguindo carregar imagens https de uma api.
Se eu realizar uma compilação no Windows Phone as imagens são carregadas normalmente já no android não, por isso pergunto, como corrigir ?

Vejam as imagens

**Android:**

[image: Android]

**UWP**
[image: UWP]

Estou usando o seguinte código para obter os dados através da api:

Home.cs

```
namespace AppNewsPlay.Views
{

    public partial class Home : TabbedPage
    {
        //private UltimasNoticias UltimasNoticias;
        List<UltimasNoticias> UNoticias;

        public TabbedPage Detail { get; private set; }

        public Home()
        {


            UNoticias = new List<UltimasNoticias>();
            ObterUltimasNoticias();
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void ObterUltimasNoticias()
        {

            //   var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UNoticias);
            // var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var resp = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var uri = new HttpClient();
                uri.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.newsplay.com.br");
                var url = "/api/post/";
                var result = await uri.GetAsync(url);


                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão", "Não foi possível obter as notícias do servidor, Tente novamente mais tarde!", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão com o Servidor", ex.Message, "OK");
                return;

            }

            // transformando o retorno em objeto através do json e deserealize e retornando em lista
            var UNoticias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UltimasNoticias>>(resp);

            //Adicionando os itens ao ListView na Home.xaml
            UnoticiasList.ItemsSource = UNoticias;

        }    

        private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.SelectedItem !=null)
            {
                var selection = e.SelectedItem as UltimasNoticias;
                //DisplayAlert("Você Selecionou", selection.Post_title, "ok");         

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new PostView());
                #region DisabledSelectionHighlighting
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
                #endregion
            }



        }
```

Home.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppNewsPlay.Views.Home"
             Title=""
             Icon="LogoMobile.png"    
             >

    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <ContentPage Title="Ultimas Notícias" Icon="">
            <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout
                        Spacing="20">      
                        <Label Text="Últimas Notícias"
                               FontSize="20"                        
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"

                         />

                <ListView x:Name="UnoticiasList"
                                  HasUnevenRows="True"      
                                  SeparatorColor="White"
                                  SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
                                  >


                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>

                                            <StackLayout
                                                 Padding="20"                                          

                                                 Orientation="Vertical"
                                                >

                                                <Image Source="{Binding Guid}"
                                                                           WidthRequest="250"
                                                                           HeightRequest="150"
                                                                           VerticalOptions="Center"

                                                                            />


                                                <Label x:Name="Post_title" Text="{ Binding Post_title }"
                                                                   FontSize="16"
                                                                   FontAttributes="Bold"  

                                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                                   />

                                                <Label x:Name="Post_content" Text="{ Binding Post_content }"
                                                       FontSize="12"                                                
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                       HeightRequest="70"

                                                       />

                                                <Label x:Name="Post_ad" Text="{Binding Post_ad}"
                                                       FontSize="11"                                            
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"   
                                                       />                                        

                                            </StackLayout>                                    

                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>                            
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>                    
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>


        <ContentPage Title="Xbox" Icon="">
            <ContentPage.Content>
            </ContentPage.Content>

        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Playstation" Icon="">
            <ContentPage.Content>

            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>

    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Retorno da Api em Json
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma:

Reparei que ao exibir uma imagem, o servidor de hospedagem cria um redirecionamento antes.

Ai para contornar o problema, acessei minha api e alterei o retorno adicionando o endereço antes, conforme a imagem abaixo, feito isso o app começou a exibir as imagens no Android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]